# Android Application Pause onStop

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I want to make an application that cannot be killed or destroyed. I've tried

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
     super.onPause();
}
```

But this is not working, the application is still killed. So, is there any other way to make an application is pausing instead of stopping it? Thanks :D

Comment: You might want to read this about Activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For long running tasks, use a service.

Comment: maybe i'll try service..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about preventing an activity from being restarted for configuration changes, try adding android:configChanges to the activity tag in your manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onPause rather than the onStop method. The pausing of the activity would not guarantee that your application would not be killed if the system is low on memory and the GC kicks in.

```
  @Override
  public void onPause() {

  }
```

For more reference on Activity, check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)